# Ubuntu 20.04 unble to download linux header

Tags: kernel

I am trying to get download Linux header
so I did this:

```
dpkg-query -s linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I got

```
dpkg-query: package 'linux-headers-6.6.7-060607-generic' is not installed and no information is available
```

and I checked with:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-headers
linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic          install
linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic          install
linux-headers-6.6.7-060607          install
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04         install
```

I updated the kernel once, so I think it just messed up.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'll want to use the `linux-headers-generic` package.  This will ensure that when the kernel upgrades, you automatically install those headers, and allow easy clean up headers for old kernels.  This will allow things like your DKMS compilations to work without manual intervention or selecting specific packages.

The only reason you'd want to install a specific `linux-headers-` package is if you're doing development against specific kernels, or need old kernel headers to stick around on your system.

```bash
sudo apt remove --purge -y linux-headers*
sudo apt install -y linux-headers-generic
```